# Удалить пробел после слова

Tags: python, текст

Есть данные строки:

```
PRB req: 20
PRB RI.req: 12
PRB RI.req: 12
...
```

Подскажите, как удалить пробелы во всех строках после PRB, чтобы получилось:

```
PRBreq: 20
PRBRI.req: 12
PRBRI.req: 12
...
```

Я пишу так, как в доке:

```
mr = re.sub('PRB\s','PRB', met)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так и как правильно

Comment: А что в итоге - не работает?

Comment: Все остается, как и было

Comment: @Resto, а вы уверены, что выводите ```mr```, а не ```met``` при проверке, у меня все сработало ?

Comment: Сейчас проверю все тщательно

Comment: @n1tr0xs Проверил несколько раз, пробелы так же остаются, будто ничего не изменилось

Comment: Все решилось так: mr = re.sub('PRB\s','PRb', met) - не понял, почему ему не нравится замена на тоже самое только без пробела. Сделал одну букву прописной

Comment: Всем спасибо)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

может использовать replace?

```
 a = 'PRB RI.req: 12'
 print(a.replace('PRB ', 'PRB'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "PRB req: 20"
a = ''.join(a.split(maxsplit=1))
print(a)
```

> PRBreq: 20

Comment: У меня почему-то не меняется ничего, пробелы остаются

Comment: рискну предположить, что у вас пробел в кавычках перед join. а там пробела быть не должно. ''.join(a.split(maxsplit=1))

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = 'PRB RI.req: 12'
re.sub(r'^(.+?)\s', r'\1', a)
```